# How does gdb find the address of a variable in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a variable declared in a c++ file like this:

```
namespace {
    VelocityLongitudinal vel_lgt;
}
```

The corresponding dwarf info is

```
<1><5e08b>: Abbrev Number: 317 (DW_TAG_namespace)
    <5e08d>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x5e09e>
 <2><5e091>: Abbrev Number: 193 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <5e093>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xa5582): vel_lgt
    <5e097>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
    <5e098>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 19
    <5e099>   DW_AT_type        : <0x5bed3>
    <5e09d>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
 <2><5e09d>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

We see that there is no DW_AT_linkage_name and no DW_AT_location

In the symbol table (readelf -s) I find. The address, 21a0a0, matches the address gdb reports (print &'(anonymous namespace)::vel_lgt')

```
42: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS vehiclemotionstate_server
43: 000000000021a0a0    24 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17vel_lgt
```

How does gdb find that? vehiclemotionstate_serve.cpp is the name of the file in which the variable is declared. It seems unlikely that gdb would search for entries with matching last characters in the symbol table entries for a certain cpp file. And if so, how would it distinguish between two different declarations of the same name in files with the same name?

Comment: Good to know we can use names between single quote strings since (, spaces, and ) are not valid as is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does gdb find that?

By reading the symbol table (equivalent to what `readelf -s` does), in addition to reading the debug info.

> It seems unlikely that gdb would search for entries with matching last characters

It doesn't. The name you found *demangles* to `(anonymous namespace)::vel_lgt` (except you appear to have made a cut/paste error: the actual name should be `_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17vel_lgtE`).

> how would it distinguish between two different declarations of the same name in files with the same name?

It would tell you that there is more than one instance if you ask, e.g.

```
(gdb) info var vel_lgt
All variables matching regular expression "vel_lgt":

File t.cc:
2:      static int (anonymous namespace)::vel_lgt;

File t1.cc:
2:      static int (anonymous namespace)::vel_lgt;
```

Note that it's actually quite hard to tell GDB  *which* of the two instances to print -- `print vel_lgt` just prints the first one, with no easy way to ask for the other one. I believe there is an open GDB bug about this, but I can't find it.

**Update:**

> The name mangling algorithm - is it the same for every compiler?

No. It's the same for ABI-compatible compilers, and (intentionally) different for incompatible ones (so you don't accidentally link code compiled with two different ABI-incompatible compilers together and than debug the resulting crashes).

> Is the mangling algorithm easily accessible in any way?

The *mangling* algorithm is only really useful to the compiler.

Presumably you want the *demangling* one (going from `_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_17vel_lgtE` to `(anonymous namespace)::vel_lgt`).

That one is available via the `c++filt` or `cxxfilt` programs, and also via [__cxa_demangle()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html#76957f5810098d2ffb5c62f43eda1c6d) routine provided by most C++ runtime libraries.

Comment: The name mangling algorithm - is it the same for every compiler?

Is the mangling algorithm easily accessible in any way? I found mangle.c from gcc sources but it's a bit tricky to reuse and GPL doesn't go well with my employer for this project.

Comment: @user2052153 I've updated the answer. It's a pretty different question though; try to avoid asking additional questions in comments -- ask a new question instead (it's free :-)

Comment: Thanks! I need find the address of a variable in anonymous namespace and hence I'm asking how gdb does it. I asked about the mangling algorithm because one approach would be to use that and then look up the mangled name in the symbol table. I followed the links your provided but didn't find any mangle() routine - does that mean that gdb de-mangles every entry in the symbol table and then uses that for lookup?

Comment: @user2052153 "does that mean that gdb de-mangles every entry in the symbol table and then uses that for lookup" Yes, and you should do the same. It's not expensive and significantly more foolproof than trying to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why do you say it's more foolproof than trying to mangle?

Comment: @user2052153 Because "mangled -> demangled" transformation is well-defined (there is a standard for it), and the opposite is not (and varies between different compilers and different versions of the same compiler).